# How to Bind ObervableCollection or IEnumerable to Flow Document Table

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, flowdocument

How Can I Bind an ObservableCollection or IEnumerable property in my ViewModel to a Table Defined by an Inline FlowDocument? I'm not sure whether it is the correct approach. I want to print an Invoice from my view model(I thought FlowDocument might be an easy method to print).

Suppose I have a Property `Items` in my ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _Items;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items;
        }
        set
        {
            _Items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
```

In Xaml: MainWindow.xaml

```
....
<FlowDocument>
   <Paragraph>
     <Run Text="Sample text"/>
   </Paragraph>

   ...

   <Table <!-- I cannot find ItemsSource Or anything similar --> >
        <!-- How can i dynamically generate rows and add them here from Items in ViewModel 

             Something like Datagrid's DataGridTextColumn ?
         -->
   </Table>
</FlowDocument>
```

FlowDocument is not a seperate file or an xps. It is embedded inside my MainWindow.xaml file

I'm a beginner and not sure how to do it.

Any help appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Had to get back to my history, yeah we experienced this before we found this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx) which says "there is no support for data binding in flow documents". So we decided to use itemscontrol instead and didn't use FlowDocument at all.

But here is a sample workaround,

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp3.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="Sample text"/>
        </Paragraph>
        <Table x:Name="Table1">
        </Table>
    </FlowDocument>

</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using WpfApp3.ViewModel;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainViewModel VM => (MainViewModel) DataContext;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BuildTable();
        }

        private void BuildTable()
        {
            foreach (ItemViewModel item in VM.Items)
            {
                TableRow nameRow = BuildRow(item.Name);

                TableRowGroup group = new TableRowGroup();
                group.Rows.Add(nameRow);

                Table1.RowGroups.Add(group);
            }
        }

        private static TableRow BuildRow(string content)
        {
            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock
            {
                Text = content
            };

            Block block1 = new BlockUIContainer(textBlock);

            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Blocks.Add(block1);

            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewModel->MainViewModel.cs`

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfApp3.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            PopulateData();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _Items;
        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
        {
            get => _Items;
            set
            {
                _Items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #region Stub

        private void PopulateData()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>
            {
                new ItemViewModel
                {
                    Name = "Item 1",
                },
                new ItemViewModel
                {
                    Name = "Item 2",
                }
            };
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

`ViewModel->ItemViewModel.cs`

```
namespace WpfApp3.ViewModel
{
    public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: But I want All the rows in an ObesrvableCollection  Not just one.

Comment: I want to populate the Table with every row in Items ObervableCollection

Comment: can you please direct me to some reference regarding ItemsControl with flowdocument

Comment: No you can't have ItemsControl in FlowDocument we didn't use FlowDocument at all, but there's a work around, you can build your table in your code-behind. I'll update my answer.